# What are the VS2010 Navigate to Next/Prev function declaration hotkeys?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

In the Access VB6 code editor Ctrl-Up and Ctrl-Down will jump to the next/prev function declaration.

This is quite a handy navigation tool and I can't seem to find it in VS2010.

I've done some searching on google and stackoverflow and can't seem to find any reference to it.

Does anyone know if these hotkeys exist at all in VS2010?

If they don't, how the hell can they not exist in a context aware IDE like VS2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes hot keys exist: http://www.dofactory.com/ShortCutKeys/ShortCutKeys.aspx

And to move to separate declarations:
shift+ctrl+1/shift+ctrl+2

Comment: These don't seem to work for me.  Any idea what the actual commands are called in the VS2010 hotkey editor?
Also judging by the description on that page it looks like that's more for navigating around based on the variable/function under the cursor.

Comment: It depends on which language you are using. For each language microsoft provides a pdf file which corresponds to separate hot key collections.

Comment: Ahh Cheers.  They don't seem to have the hotkey commands that I'm looking for but those pdfs are very helpful none-the-less.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think they exist in VS2010, we work in both VS6 and 2010 and it's infuriating not to have these commands.

Answer (score 0):

I'm OCD with automation these days, have made a lot of macros to help me navigate. Following is some VB macro code that will do what you want in C (and probably C++ too). You can create a macro in Visual Studio and add these lines to it. The regular expression to detect function declarations is likely not perfect but I've been using them for a week now and they've worked great for me. You can map these 2 macros to the key bindings you want, Ctrl+Up or Ctrl+Down if you like. If anyone improves the regular expression I would love to see the updated version.

```
Imports System
Imports EnvDTE
Imports EnvDTE80
Imports EnvDTE90
Imports EnvDTE90a
Imports EnvDTE100
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Module NavigationMacros
    Private Function IsFunctionDeclaration(ByRef LineText As String) As Boolean
        If Regex.IsMatch(LineText, "^[^\s\d\W\(\)]+[^\(\)]+\s+[^\s\d\W\(\)]+\s*\([^\(\)]*\)\s*$") Then
            IsFunctionDeclaration = True
        Else
            IsFunctionDeclaration = False
        End If
    End Function

    Private Function GetLineText(ByRef EditPoint As EnvDTE.EditPoint) As String
        EditPoint.StartOfLine()
        GetLineText = EditPoint.GetText(EditPoint.LineLength)
    End Function

    Sub GoToPreviousFunctionDeclaration()
        Dim Selection As EnvDTE.TextSelection
        Dim EditPoint As EnvDTE.EditPoint
        Dim LineText As String

        Selection = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection
        EditPoint = Selection.TopPoint.CreateEditPoint

        EditPoint.LineUp()

        While IsFunctionDeclaration(GetLineText(EditPoint)) = False And Not EditPoint.AtStartOfDocument
            EditPoint.LineUp()
        End While

        If Not EditPoint.AtEndOfDocument Then
            Selection.MoveToLineAndOffset(EditPoint.Line, 1)
        End If
    End Sub

    Sub GoToNextFunctionDeclaration()
        Dim Selection As EnvDTE.TextSelection
        Dim EditPoint As EnvDTE.EditPoint
        Dim LineText As String

        Selection = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection
        EditPoint = Selection.TopPoint.CreateEditPoint

        EditPoint.LineDown()

        While IsFunctionDeclaration(GetLineText(EditPoint)) = False And Not EditPoint.AtEndOfDocument
            EditPoint.LineDown()
        End While

        If Not EditPoint.AtEndOfDocument Then
            Selection.MoveToLineAndOffset(EditPoint.Line, 1)
        End If
    End Sub
End Module
```